# BindingAdapter only work once and doesn't work after using notifyPropertyChanged

Tags: android, android-databinding

In my simple application i would like to change one image view url by clicking on button after setting default url into that, for example in imageView i have google logo image and after clicking on button that updating to image stackoverflow logo

unfortunately my implemented code for `BindingAdapter` that only work once when i run application,showing google logo image and after changing image url and using `notifyPropertyChanged` that doesn't work

ImageBindingAdapter class:

```
object ImageBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("imageUrl", "placeholder", requireAll = false)
    @JvmStatic
    fun loadImage(imageView: ImageView, imageUrl: String, placeholder: Drawable) {
        if (imageUrl != "") {
            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_not_found)
                    .error(R.drawable.image_not_found)
                    .into(imageView)
        } 
    }
}
```

my `User` class which that have image url

```
class User : BaseObservable() {
    var username: String? = null
    var password: String? = null
    var profilePicUrl: String? = null
        @Bindable
        set(profilePicUrl) {
            field = profilePicUrl
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.profilePicUrl)
        }
}
```

and then my `LoginActivity`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding: LoginActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.login_activity)
    binding.viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, LoginViewModelFactory(this)).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

    val user = User()
    user.username = "xxxx"
    user.password = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    user.profilePicUrl = ""

    binding.user = user

    val handlers = ClickHandler()
    handlers.user = user
    binding.handlers = handlers

}
```

`ClickHandler` class:

```
class ClickHandler {
    var user: User? = null

    fun clickOnLoginButton(view: View) {
        user?.profilePicUrl = "https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/1-370x247.jpg"
    }
}
```

**TIP:** this `ClickHandler` after multiple clicking on that work fine, i tested

layout xml

```
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="@{handlers.clickOnLoginButton}"
    ... />

<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    ...
    app:imageUrl="@{user.profilePicUrl}"
    app:placeholder="@{@drawable/img_wizard_1}"
    ... />
```

Comment: As you've written that `ClickHandler` is working & you're passing same **url** again and again in `ClickHandler` hence not changing **url** after first change, Should that be the issue?

Comment: @JeelVankhede yes, sure, in first initialing i dont set any url into imageview, and after click on button i set url and i expect Databinding work again to load image from url

Comment: @JeelVankhede my post updated, please review that, thanks

Comment: Try placing some log statement to your method `loadImage` to check if your binding adapter gets called every time or not.

Comment: @JeelVankhede `Log` work on running application inside `loadImage` but it doen't log me after click on button

Comment: @JeelVankhede and inside `set(profilePicUrl)` work fine after mutiple clicking on button

Comment: I think the issue is, you're having **null** user object inside your `ClickHandler` class. So, you'll need to pass it from xml when you bind listener to your button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191790/discussion-between-doldurma-and-jeel-vankhede).

Comment: check this: set "binding.lifecycleOwner = this"  in yout onCreate